# How to duplicate RS232 signal to 2 ports by software?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm currently using C# to fetch information coming from RS232 port,
but there is another program that is using the port, too.
I'm told that I have to keep both of them (mine and the existing one) working.
In both softwares I find out that if one occupy the port, another will fail to open it.
So I wonder if I can duplicate the signal to another virtual port?
Either by another software or in C#.
I've tried some utilities but they don't have this function.
Thanks for help!

Comment: y cant u use different port number ? or else when u use same port continuously when your process starts, i think first u can close the port then open , like serialport.close() then serialport .open(). Its just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Sadly, my objetive is to keep both programs up and running, both getting signals.

Comment: yeah you are using one port RS232, I think you can use different port number for same port , like 4000, 4001, port number will be different , port will be one.

Comment: Is that another program wrote by you or?

Comment: I have used VSPE before and it does allow multiple applications to access the same RS-232 port. The 32bit version is free. http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html

Comment: The other program is written by another, and I don't have the source code.